# Docker unable to copy files to mounted volume

Tags: bash, docker

I am unable to run this command on jenkins, but i am able to run this same command on the windows powershell

```
16:13:55  + docker run -v /opt/jenkins/workspace/tas/zigbee-gateway/hostoutput/:/home/jenkins/output_to_host tas-gateway cp -a /home/jenkins/output/. /home/jenkins/output_to_host
16:13:55  cp: cannot create regular file '/home/jenkins/output_to_host/./Gateway_INTL_1.0.4-10_ramips_24kec.ipk': Permission denied
16:13:55  cp: cannot create regular file '/home/jenkins/output_to_host/./Gateway_CN_1.0.4-10_ramips_24kec.ipk': Permission denied
16:13:55  cp: cannot create regular file '/home/jenkins/output_to_host/./Gateway_TEST_1.0.4-10_ramips_24kec.ipk': Permission denied
16:13:55  cp: preserving times for '/home/jenkins/output_to_host/.': Operation not permitted
```

What am I missing out? the jenkins is run on amazon linux

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jenkins' user does not have write permission to the specified folder.

edit: please try

```
sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Comment: If they are using PowerShell probably they don't have `sudo` or `usermod`.

Comment: no @tripleee my local is windows, the remote jenkins is linux

Comment: Yeah so your local computer probably doesn't have `sudo` or `usermod`, does it?

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ - information which should be in the question, as the solution will be different on a Windows host.